# Как изменить жадность preg_replace при работе с массивом паттернов?

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Имеем следующий тестовый код.

```
    $subject = "Мама мыла раму, дочь чертила пентаграмму";

    $array = array(
        'Мама',
        'Мама мыла',
        'Мама мыла раму',
        'Мама мыла раму, дочь',
        'Мама мыла раму, дочь чертила',
    );

    $array_pattern = array();

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $array_pattern[] = "#^{$value}#i";
    }

    $result = preg_replace($array_pattern, '', $subject);

    echo $result;
```

В результате получаем строку **мыла раму, дочь чертила пентаграмму** вместо желаемой строки **пентаграмму**.
Как изменить поведение работы `preg_replace` в данном случае?

P.S. Вопрос связан с этой [темой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626819/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Comment: Можно отсортировать исходный массив по убыванию длины)

Comment: вообщето я это делал не помогает...

Comment: Странно с этим кодом действительно сортировка помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отсортировать исходный массив по убыванию длины:

```
<?php

$subject = "Мама мыла раму, дочь чертила пентаграмму";

$array = array(
    'Мама',
    'Мама мыла',
    'Мама мыла раму',
    'Мама мыла раму, дочь',
    'Мама мыла раму, дочь чертила',
);

usort($array, function($a, $b){return strlen($b) - strlen($a);});

$array_pattern = array();

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $array_pattern[] = "#^{$value}#i";
}

$result = preg_replace($array_pattern, '', $subject);

echo $result; // ' пентаграмму'
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/3kaHo)